# React App .env content keeps leaking in build

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-functions, server-side, api-key

I currently have a React App Deployed with Firebase that contains all my Firebase credentials (Api keys, storage buckets, ect). I seen a lot of posts telling me to store keys on the server and deliver on request. How would I get that done as a complete beginner to this.

Comment: Please include the posts that say otherwise. Firebase credentials are supposed to be on the App. If you are using Firebase storage, firebase firestore this is expected.

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/security/compromised-credentials#separate_credentials_from_code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Firebase specifically [you can keep the keys in the code](https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/api-keys#general-info), as they are not used for access control. Access control is done using Rules instead.

The only cases in which [restrictions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/api-keys#apply-restrictions) are recommended for API keys is when using them for Firebase ML and Password-based authentication.